# Ember: Detect when an object is saved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Somewhere in my ember code I have

```
myobject.save();
```

I want to detect when that saving is done. Because then the object has gotten an ID.

I know the `save` method returns a promise and I can use `then()` to execute code when saving is done. But that pattern won't work in my case.

Somewhere else in my code I am doing several things and then I want to get the ID of `myobject`. Then I might have to wait until the object has finished the save and has gotten the ID. I need the id because it shall be part of a transition to a dynamic route. The code in a route action handler looks like this:

```
myobject.DoSomeStuffAndThenSave();
....
// Do some other stuff that might take some time
....
this.transitionTo('myroute', myobject.get('id'));
```

I guess I need to check the `isSaving` flag and and in the case the `isSaving` flag is true, I should listen to the `isUpdated` event. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return another promise in your method of 'do some other stuff that might take some time' and then put your route transition in the .then() of that promise:

```
// models/myobject.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  // ...

  aLongRunningMethod () {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // do whatever long process you need to do here
      resolve();
    });
  }
});

// whatever file you're saving the model in
myobject.aLongRunningMethod().then(() => {
  myobject.save().then(obj => {
    this.transitionTo('myroute', obj.get('id'));
  });
});
```

Or if you need to save it first, you can use the methods in the opposite order:

```
myobject.save().then(obj => {
  obj.aLongRunningMethod().then(() => {
    this.transitionTo('myroute', obj.get('id'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanx, I got it to work with Promises. It is a little hard to grasp, but promises beyond simple `save().then()` is definitely a useful technique.